# windows 7 findstr

Tags: search, grep, windows-7-x64, findstr

I used the `findstr` and tried to find some key word errors in an output file.  I saved all the error code inside a `finddata.txt`.  The search did run for a while, but I look at the results, The search placed each line with `$findstr /c: "ORA-" text.err` in the result file.  The result file was huge, so I know something is wrong.

I obviously only need the results when `findstr` find something for me.

`findstr /g:finddata.txt /f:text.err > text_err.out`

-- here is the MSFT technet manual:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation you will see:

```
/f: file   : Reads file list from the specified file.
```

For each input line you asking FindStr to find a file with name of the data in the inputline, you don't need to do this. Just specify the file on the line.

Remove the **/f:**

```
findstr /g:finddata.txt text.err > text_err.out
```

Comment: I got the same issue with a huge file generated.  Let me test one search string at a time and report back if it works.